# I need to convert sql to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

This is my sql command:

```
select 
    b.Brand, 
    count(b.Brand) as BrandCount,
    SUM(a.Qty) as DeviceCount 
from (
    select * from DeviceList
) as a 
join DeviceMaster as b 
    on a.DeviceMasterId = b.Id
group by b.Brand
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
var v1 = (from p in ghostEntities.DeviceMasters 
          join c in ghostEntities.DeviceLists on p.Id equals c.DeviceMasterId 
          select new table_Model { 
            Id = c.Id, 
            qty = c.Qty.Value, 
            month = c.DMonth, 
            brand = p.Brand, 
            model = p.Model, 
            memory = p.Memory
          }).ToList();
```

I am getting the values form two tables but can't group them or add the values.

Comment: var v1 = (from p in ghostEntities.DeviceMasters
                  join c in ghostEntities.DeviceLists on p.Id equals c.DeviceMasterId
                  select new table_Model
                  {
                      Id = c.Id,
                      qty = c.Qty.Value,
                      month = c.DMonth,
                      brand = p.Brand,
                      model = p.Model,
                      memory = p.Memory
                  }).ToList();

Comment: I am getting the values form two tables...but cant group them or add the values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you group by a table, **you lose access to the fields of the other table** in the join operation, a possible workaround would be:

```
var results = (from a in DeviceList
                join b in DeviceMaster
                on a.DeviceMasterId equals b.Id
                group new { a, b } by new { b.Brand } into grp
                select new
                {
                    Brand = grp.Key.Brand,
                    BrandCount = grp.Count(),
                    DeviceCount = grp.Sum(x=> x.a.Qty.GetValueOrDefault())
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: hi, the brand and brandcount works, but device count is giving an error.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Updated, check the answer

Answer (score 2):

You should add group by into your LINQ query and use Distinct().Count() and Sum() aggregation functions:

```
var query = from a in ghostEntities.DeviceList
   join b in ghostEntities.DeviceMaster on a.DeviceMasterId equals b.Id
   group b by b.Brand into g
   select new { g.Key, count =g.Select(x => x.Brand).Distinct().Count(), sum = g.Sum(x => x.Qty) };
```

You can find a lot of LINQ samples at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Actually this line "g.Sum(x => x.Qty)" will not compile, x will be of type DeviceMaster and not DeviceList